# Schema Extensions Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Env: Developer Account aka using sandbox and through graph explorer.

I am having trouble updating a custom field added through schemaExtensions. Here are the steps:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions
{
    "id": {schemaName},
    "description": "Meta data",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Event"
    ],
    "owner": {app_id},
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "Pid",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get a 201 response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions/$entity",
    "id": "extiv30x2jc_{schemaName}",
    "description": "Meta data",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Event"
    ],
    "status": "InDevelopment",
    "owner": {app_id},
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "Pid",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then create a event as below:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
{
    "subject": "My event",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2021-02-25T22:45:11.110Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2021-02-25T22:45:11.110Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

Event is successfully created and I note the **id** of the event. I then patch the event, since it is not possible to create an instance and update the custom field simultaneously.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}
{
    "extiv30x2jc_{schemaName}": {
        "Pid": "1"
    }
}
```

For which I get a 200 response like below:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users({graph_explorer_profile_id})/events/$entity"
}
```

To search for the event to see if the custom field has been updated, i use this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}
```

But I cannot find the custom field **Pid**. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding

> But I cannot find the custom field Pid. What did I do wrong here?

*by default* schema extensions are not getting returned. Use  [`select` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter) to return schema extension along with default event properties:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}?$select=extiv30x2jc_{schemaName}
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim! I can now see it! Seeing other posts and documentation, I will not be able to filter by that custom field right?

Comment: Since mine is event, this is applicable?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#extensions "Filtering on schema extension properties (using the $filter expression) is not supported for Outlook entity types - contact, event, message, or post."

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{id}/extensions
```

Comment: I get this: `"message": "The OData request is not supported.",`